# gethostbyaddr Error only on 1 server

Tags: python, sockets

Running the following on my production server throws an error

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr("<IP ADDRESS>")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

Running that same code, with the same IP on a different server works fine. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Maybe no DNS Server available?

Comment: Maybe the servers have differently configured name servers? Does `host <IP ADDRESS>` on the command line work on both computers?

Comment: the `host` gives the same result on both server `Host 156.111.76.208.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. How would I test the DNS server availability?

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine" then? What result do you expect?

Comment: If `host` cannot find the IP, how do you expect it to work in Python?

Comment: @tripleee It returns the hostname, aliaslist and ipaddrlist

Comment: If this is not available from DNS, where is it configured? Speculating you have a local configuration in `/etc/hosts` on one host, but not on the other, or that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` differs between them. Seems not to be a programming problem, anyway.

Comment: @user4815162342 sorry I think I put in the wrong IP for it, I'm still getting a not found on the server but it's working on my computer. The problem also seems to be on and off, some of the IP address seem to have started working will others are still failing.